# Что будет напечатано в результате выполнения процедуры?

Tags: pascal, олимпиада

Напишите с объяснениями пожалуйста

```
procedure proc;

var

   x,y,z:integer;

begin

   x:=17;

   y:=x div 5;

   z:=y mod 2;

   write(z);

end;

begin

   proc;

end.
```

Comment: Запустите процедуру и посмотрите результат

Comment: @andreymal я запускал процедуру,НО мне нужно объяснить этот ответ,то есть как он получился,поэтому я и написал с полным решением.

Comment: Что конкретно непонятно в этом коде?

Comment: @andreymal вообще это pascal и олимпиадное задание,я учился только на python ,поэтому для меня тут все не понятно.Просто нужно написать объяснение как вычисляется ответ

Comment: Ну пробежитесь глазами по любому учебнику pascal да и всё. Если вы и правда умеете в python, то это не займёт у вас много времени

Comment: @andreymal я вообщем понимаю что там в начале создают три переменнных потом операции с ними выполняются

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это целое и остаток от деления
В питоновском синтаксисе

```
z=(17//5)%2
```